replace in old project exists Django User model to my User model
I have an old project in which there is a user model that was made by default.
Next, we were asked to change the default user model.
We have redefined the user model as:
class Staff(AbstractUser):
    # ... new fields ...

    # no need in model
    user_permissions = None
    groups = None

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        swappable = "AUTH_USER_MODEL"

Next, we added it to the settings.py file:
# user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'test.Staff'
# django authentication backend
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # Django's default authentication backend
    'test.backends.ModelBackend',  # Custom authentication backend
]

the necessary lines and we can't start the migration (just re-run for tests).
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'test.staff', but app 'test' doesn't provide model 'staff'

Please tell me how to properly replace users in django.

Changing the default user model to a custom one in an existing project is quite difficult (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project).  A better approach would be to leave the User model as the default, and use a OneToOneField to link Staff to it (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).
